# How to skip two tags in single --tag, while running cucumber scenarios?

Tags: cucumber

I have written a few cucumber features and also tagged some scenarios with @wip and @test.
I am running cucumber features and want to skip the scenarios which are tagged with @wip and @test so I used the below mentioned line to skip the same.

```
1.   --format pretty --quiet --color --tags ~@wip,~@test
```

But at the time of executing scenarios, I found all the scenarios tagged with @wip and @test are still getting executed. Then I changed the above line as:

```
2.  --format pretty --quiet --color --tags ~@wip, --tags ~@test
```

Then it is skipping the scenarios tagged with @wip and @test.

So, I want to know is it possible to skip two or multiple tags in single --tag i.e mentioned in point 1?

Comment: Have you checked Logically ANDing and ORing Tags? https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

Comment: @denis.solonenko, thnx for you quick reply. I have checked the link, and from that link only i got point 2. But for point 1 nothing is mentioned like that. Any other solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is
1.--format pretty --quiet --color --tags ~@wip,~@test

The comma means that the conditions are OR-ed.
It says: all scenarios that are not @wip OR are not @test
So scenarios with only @wip are executed

The solution is to use quotes, than the conditions are AND-ed

1.--format pretty --quiet --color --tags "~@wip","~@test"

Comment: Depending on which version of Cucumber you are using, you might need to use "not" instead of `~` and "or" instead of a comma. So it might would be "not (@wip or @test)" or something similar.